# How to include different resolution icons with Android App?

Tags: android, icons, manifest

The Android docs indicate that I should ship with different icons for different resolution phone screens.  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

- `res/drawable-ldpi/my_icon.png       // icon image for low density`
- `res/drawable-mdpi/dpi/my_icon.png   // icon for medium density`
- `res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png       // icon image for high density`

This does not work when compiling with Eclipse for the Android.  Does anyone has an example of a manifest file that works for multiple resolution icons?

Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: Can you paste your error that you are getting?

Comment: i have seen examples where you make an xml file that is used as a switch. you set your icon to that xml file and then it has some mechanism to determine which icon to use. im not exactly sure how to do that for your case, but im sure you can find examples of this (particularly for tabhost)

Comment: Also, please post your manifest file, if that is what you think you are having problems with.

Comment: Which is the your project target? the different content strategy is available 
only from Anddroid 1.6

Comment: I think the extra `dpi` directory for `mdpi` is a typo (in the docs), and that it should be `res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png`

Answer (score 0):

You should still refer to your icon as `@drawable/my_icon`

The [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources) section of the Developers Guide goes even further and shows how you can create more complex aliases, in the following section:

> **Creating alias resources**
>
> When you have a resource that you'd like to use for more than one device configuration (but not for all configurations), you do not need to put the same resource in each alternative resource directory. Instead, you can (in some cases) create an alternative resource that acts as an alias for a resource saved in your default resource directory.
>
> > **Note:** Not all resources offer a mechanism by which you can create an alias to another resource. In particular, animation, menu, raw, and other unspecified resources in the `xml/` directory do not offer this feature.
>
> For example, imagine you have an application icon, `icon.png`, and need unique version of it for different locales. However, two locales, English-Canadian and French-Canadian, need to use the same version. You might assume that you need to copy the same image into the resource directory for both English-Canadian and French-Canadian, but it's not true. Instead, you can save the image that's used for both as `icon_ca.png` (any name other than `icon.png`) and put it in the default `res/drawable/` directory. Then create an `icon.xml` file in `res/drawable-en-rCA/` and `res/drawable-fr-rCA/` that refers to the `icon_ca.png` resource using the `<bitmap>` element. This allows you to store just one version of the PNG file and two small XML files that point to it. (An example XML file is shown below.)
>
> **Drawable**
>
> To create an alias to an existing drawable, use the `<bitmap>` element. For example:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:src="@drawable/icon_ca" />
> ```
>
> If you save this file as `icon.xml` (in an alternative resource directory, such as `res/drawable-en-rCA/`), it is compiled into a resource that you can reference as `R.drawable.icon`, but is actually an alias for the `R.drawable.icon_ca` resource (which is saved in `res/drawable/`).

However you do not need to create aliases if you simply have different icons for different screen densities. The resource directory qualifiers shown in [the table you link to](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) are `ldpi`, `mdpi`, and `hdpi`. The qualifiers are used when [locating alternative resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) (emphasis added):

> The `hdpi` qualifier indicates that the resources in that directory are for devices with a high-density screen. While the images in each drawable directory are sized for a specific screen density, the filenames are the same. This way, the resource ID that you use to reference the `icon.png` or `background.png` image is always the same, but ***Android selects the version of that drawable that best matches the current device configuration***.

Comment: If I refer to my icon as @drawable, can I put different resolution icons into drawable-ldpi etc, and will the runtime find the correct resolution icon?  Do you have a sample manifest file that you could post?

Comment: @Gerry, yes. I updated my answer to include a whole of heap of the docs. Not entirely relevant to just locating alternative resources, but going even further and overriding the image for just some locales.